# Can I actually ignore my ignored tags?

Tags: support, tags

I decided to finally go ahead start using the ignored tags feature. So I added "homework" as an ignored tag - but the homework questions are still there on the main page, they're just greyed out, like this:

[image]

Is it possible to make them disappear entirely? This is a last-ditch attempt to filter out some of the noise on this site and make it seem interesting again, and if I still have to scroll past all the greyed-out homework questions it's not going to be as effective.

Comment: Are you sure you're on the main page? Ignored tags are fully ignored for me on the SO main page.

Comment: Huh. The same happens for me. Bug?

Comment: I added an image just in case.

Comment: One thing you can do is use a user style (using a user script or an extension like Stylish) that sets the style for `.tagged-ignored` to `display:none`

Comment: in your user profile/preferences.

Comment: Some of the hw questions are good, though; you shouldn't filter them.

Comment: @DImension10AbhimanyuPS I know some of them are good, and I don't really want to filter anything - but lately there is just too much noise and I've been losing interest in the site as a result. I'm hoping that this crude filter will help to change that a little.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately it's September, and we're getting a LOT of HW questions, as usual.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, this seems to be a preference.

Go to [your preferences page](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current)

Tick the "hide ignored posts" checkbox  near the bottom:

[image]

Note that this hides *all* posts tagged "homework", even if they are tagged with your favorited tags. Probably desired behavior in this case :)

Comment: Ah, great. I wasn't actually aware that I had a preferences page!